# Javascript set text-shadow from angle

Tags: javascript, css, trigonometry

If I have an angle such as 45 degrees and I want to make a text shadow based on that angle with a certain length how could I do this with javascript (I'd prefer no jquery)?

---

Example:

36.87 degrees

```
text-shadow: 4px 3px blue;
```

53.13 degrees

```
text-shadow: 3px 4px blue;
```

Comment: This is only a simple math calculation with `r*cosθ` being x and `r*sinθ` being y!

Comment: you can use `transform: rotate(45deg); ` @MicahCowell

Comment: No, this is not what OP wants

Comment: `document.getElementById("mytextid").style.textShadow = "4px 4px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1)";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer with all the code:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("myText");
var deg = 45; // Your angle
var rad = -deg * (Math.PI/180)
var length = 8;
el.style.textShadow = (length * Math.cos(rad)) + 'px ' +
                      (length * Math.sin(rad)) + 'px ' +
                      '8px pink';
```

```html
<h1 id='myText'>My Text</h1>
```